# vscode Intellisense of importing modules stopped working

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I just updated ***Visual Studio Code***, and suddenly when I import modules in Javascript:

```
import module from './module'
```

Intellisense doesn't offer to complete me when addressing the file I want to import.

When I mouseover `'./module'` I do get to see the address, and the module is being loaded just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> [> NPM Intellisense <](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leizongmin.node-module-intellisense)
>   maybe do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

A friend discovered me to this

***Path Automcomplete*** - vscode extension

it solves my issue :)